# Jetpack Compose Bottomsheet with empty sheet content is always expnaded

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to achieve `modalBottomSheet` by `BottomSheetScaffold` for some custom implementation.

here is my `BottomSheetScaffold`

```kotlin
BottomSheetScaffold(
    sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetState,
    sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    sheetElevation = 0.dp,
    sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 36.dp, topEnd = 36.dp),
    snackbarHost = snackBarHost,
    sheetContent = { bottomSheet() }) {
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        sheetContent()
        Scrim(
            color = Primary,
            alpha = bottomSheetState.currentFraction * 0.5f,
            onDismiss = {
                coroutineScope.launch { bottomSheetState.bottomSheetState.collapse() }
            },
            visible = bottomSheetState.bottomSheetState.targetValue != BottomSheetValue.Collapsed && bottomSheetState.bottomSheetState.currentValue != BottomSheetValue.Collapsed
        )
    }
}
```

When this scaffold is called by some screen, the `sheetContent()` will be replaced as screen content. My problem here is when `bottomSheet()` is empty on that screen and thus there is no height, bottom sheet state think it is expanded while I just not put composable inside `bottomSheet()` and it just fill based on some condition with no default composable. Because of that the `Scrim()` function will be visible and when I click on it this exception will throw

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The target value must have an associated anchor.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems while `sheetContent` is necessary for BottomSheetScaffold there is no way to deal with empty value because `BottomSheetState` class that handle's swiping need anchor to get height and empty value cause's unexpected result

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug introduced in latest release of compose 1.2.x. To stop showing bottom sheet at start, I only add sheetContent if data is not null(this was not possible in previous release1.1.x). Now I have another issue. The click event to expanding bottomSheet won't trigger at first try. I always need to click it twice.